How to get process output into variable without executing subshell
I have a script reading an identifier
ID=$(GPU.py --get)
#Do something
GPU.py --release $ID

Now from GPU.py I want to test what was the PID of the --get calling process so I call
os.getppid(). On release I can then test if the given ID was released by the same process.
~~In case of the Bash script above, it does not work, while it calls subshell.~~
Actually it does! I was confused but as accepted answer points out there is some optimization not running subshell! The only problem was I have rewritten it as below and it stopped working.
I was thinking I will be lucky doing
read ID < <(GPU.py --get)

But it seems also here subshell is created and os.getppid() does not return PID of the script. Could you help me to fix it? And the fix is not to call os.getpppid() while I can call the Python program not only from Bash.

I'm pretty sure this is a bash issue, not a Python one, so I've swapped the tags back to how they were originally.

I think it's not ID = $(GPU.py --get) but ID=$(GPU.py --get). Tools like dotenv allows spaces, but actually, the shells doesn't allow them.

``from GPU.py I want to test what was the PID of the --get calling process so I call os.getppid().I do not understand that part. Of which process? Subshells are created and they come and go, if you want the pid of the shell, then use $BASHPID. Why are you searching for a pid of bash from python? I think constraining the _calling convention_ of your script is going to be cumbersome for everyone. How about passing$BASHPID` as an argument?

When command substitution runs only a single command, which is your case, then bash optimizes by running directly the command without creating a subshell.
You can verify with the following :
echo $$ $(python -c 'import os; print(os.getppid())')


Note that while this is true in bash (and also zsh, ksh, dash,...) I don't think it's guaranteed to be true in all shells.


How to get process output into variable without executing subshell

You can redirect command output to a file.
GPU.py --get >file
id=$(<file)

You might be also interested in coproc.
